# Microsoft.Graph uwp always ask to login

Tags: uwp, microsoft-graph-api, outlook.com

i'm messing around with an uwp app, connecting to an outlook.com account via microsoft.graph sdk. It works fine, but the app doesn't remember the account when i have closed the app and reopen it.
When i look at other apps, which use outlook.com auth, you only have to loggon once and the app remembers the credentials.

I checked the PublicClientApplication-Class, but i found nothing where i can store the credentials.

Has anyone got this to work?

Thanks in advance,
mprattinger

Comment: Can you provide us with more information? for example the OS version,target device.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late answer. Currently it happens when i run it from visual studio in debug mode on an win10 machine (ver 10586.713) targeting the local machine